# PHP Doctrine: cannot find ClassName, but factory loading works..?

Tags: php, doctrine, autoload

I'm using PHP Doctrine and i've setup autoloading:

```
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));
```

I can create a table like so:

```
$table = Doctrine_Core::getTable('TableName');
```

**However if I try it like this, it doesn't work, what am I missing?:**

```
$table = new TableNameTable(); //Yes it should be TableNameTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a configuration mistake. Loadingtype should NOT be set to PROGRESSIVE.

Comment: hello! how do you change the configuration to disable progressive loading types?  I can't find either of these referenced in either the code or the documentation!